# (Parameters) Can a date generate a day in SSRS Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2012

Parameters: Select day of week (mon, tue, wed Etc.), Select the date of promotion (ex. 04/04/2014). I would like to eliminate the step of choosing what weekday it is. Can the parameter realize date and day?`(DATENAME(dw, tra.Date) = @DayOfWeek)` and `(tra.Date = @PromoDate)` When I change the @DayOfWeek to @PromoDate I get the following error "Cannot read the next data row for the dataset AverageHI. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)"

Comment: You are running into a conversion error. You may be trying to assign a weekday to a date value or vice versa. Why don't you just send in the @PromoDate you can extract the weekday in ssrs or sql. But why would you need to know the week day if you have the date?

Answer (score 0):

First Change your Parameter Type to "Date" type. I guess your error causes of this.
If you want to get Day from date then use

```
=WeekdayName(2,True,0)
=WeekDayName(DatePart("w",Fields!BirthDate.Value),True,0)
=WeekDayName(DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,Fields!BirthDate.Value),True,FirstDayOfWeek.System)
```